# How to add cordova plugin .so files using VS2015?

Tags: cordova, java-native-interface, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing a JS/Cordova app using VS2015.
I developed a native code library (libmyjni.so) using Android studio.
I am trying to create a Cordova plugin for android that will use my .so library.

I am assuming I need to add this .so file to my plugin code (or is this packaged some other way?)

My question is, **where would I place this native library (.so) under the plugins folder, so the plugin code (.java) file can call the method in it? are any other settings required besides this?**

Right now, the folder/file structure looks like

```
 plugins
 --example.plugin.calculator
 ----src
 ------android
 --------Calculator.java  //this is using the method in the .so library
 ----www
 ------calculator.js
 ----plugin.xml
```

**Also, how would I load a .so library in my plugin class -
 in the pluginInitialize method or as a static method ?**

Currently my plugin class looks like this:

```
    package example.plugin.calculator;

    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
    import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;

    public class Calculator extends CordovaPlugin {

    protected void pluginInitialize() {
          System.loadLibrary("myjni"); //contains the "average" method
    }

    public static final String ACTION_AVERAGE = "average"; 

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, 
                       CallbackContext callbackContext) 
       throws JSONException {

      if (ACTION_AVERAGE.equals(action)) { 
        JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);
        String n1 = arg_object.getString("n1");
        String n2 = arg_object.getString("n2");
        double answer = average(n1, n2);
        String result = String.valueOf(answer);
        callbackContext.success(result);
        return true;    
      }

      callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
      return false;

     }

     public native double average(int n1, int n2);

     static {
         System.loadLibrary("myjni");  //contains the "average" method
     }
   }
```

Any help much appreciated,
_Thanks

Comment: Have you solve this. I am facing same problem. System.loadLibrary("myjni"); not work. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I just did a similar thing where I created a Cordova plugin to access a .so library, so I thought I'd share! Assuming your javascript can correctly call the .java file with the cordova.exec() function:

The .so file should be placed in the **/libs/armeabi** directory. Cordova should wrap this up into the .apk from there.

As for where the library should be loaded, I used the static function to insure that it could only be loaded once. I'm not sure where the pluginInitialize() method is called (if it is at all?), so I'd shy away from that.

Good luck!